# Does startActivity send a broadcast?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

Does calling startActivity send a broadcast? (and if so can I capture it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and yes, as that is essentially what is happening when you start an Activity. You are broadcasting an Intent, which is captured by another Activity with the appropriate IntentFilters set.

Comment: can you give me an example of the appropriate IntentFilters if I call something like startActivity(new Intent("com.example.class"))? I'm curious if I can register a receiver and capture the intent...thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't use intent filters in that case, when the broadcast target is explicitly specified (as package/class). I'm not 100% sure, but I think the only way to capture an Intent with a Receiver in that fashion is to make the Receiver itself the target... but you wouldn't be starting an activity doing it that way. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to register a receiver to let me know when the current foreground activity changes. I need to be able to do this without changing the base class of any activities...basically I want a global event to be fired when the foreground activity changes within my app.

Comment: what also could be a big help to me is if you knew a way to get a handle to the context in a foreground activity, different question but related to what I'm trying to do

Comment: A receiver is going to be overkill for that. They're generally used to listen for events outside of the application (incoming call, screen off, etc). For your global event, you could create a subclass of Application with static method(s) that are called by Activity-level lifecycle methods (onPause, onCreate, etc). Specify your Application subclass in the AndroidManifest.xml file - ex. application android:name=".MyApplication" ... > and you should be good.

Comment: For Context, you can call getApplicationContext() from within any Activity. It doesn't matter where you get it from (foreground Activity vs background), so you don't need to maintain handles to Activity-specific Contexts... doing so is actually an easy way of creating memory leaks.

Comment: The issue is I'm trying to package this in a library so I can't modify onPause or onCreate of any activities. I am using getApplicationContext but I can't use it to do things like display a dialog. Thanks for the responses!